# My project doesn't open correctly?

Tags: android, gradle

What could be the reason when I open the project in my PC it gives me this error?

[image]

However, if I open it open it in another PC it opens well.

Comment: Look if you have some absolute path somewhere in the project and replace it with a relative path.

Answer (score 0):

the project works well now. when I change the project location path because I notice it is too long